# GitHub gets confused about what account I'm using when making a PR

Tags: git, github

I have 2 GitHub accounts, one personal and another one that's shared on my enterprise in order to make commits. Every time I make a PR with the enterprise account, I want to be able to review (and approve) my own PRs with my personal account, however, every time I try, GitHub sends me the following message

`This PR needs approval from someone other than (MyPersonalAccount) because they were the last pusher`

Obviously, that's not the case, since all my commits I did on my branch were done using the enterprise account. I checked using the `git config --list` command, and both the username and email are the ones of my enterprise account.

How can I fix this issue and tell GitHub that I didn't did any pushes to the branch with my personal account?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here isn't so much the account used to create the commit (the author), but instead the credentials used to authenticate to GitHub when you pushed the commit (the pusher). If both accounts have write access to the same repo, then it's likely that your client used your personal credentials to push instead of the work credentials.

I'm not sure how GitHub would want to fix the current situation, but https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+multiple+github+accounts should have some good guidance for working around the credential issue so that your work account is both the author and the pusher in the future.